# Codeigniter 2.1.0 forms

Tags: jquery, forms, codeigniter, jformer

I am new to codeigniter. I liked jFormer and I am wondering what is the best way to integrate jFormer with it.

what other alternative to jFormer do you recommend?

Comment: Actually [jFormer](http://liore.com/integrate-jformer-library-into-codeigniter-php-framework/) has a description on how it can be integrate to the codeigniter; apparently the link went 404. But I think this require a bit of works but it should be possible, you need to read into codeigniter documentation on javascript, library section as jFormer only has php, css and javascript.

Comment: yeah I saw that link but no where in the internet I could find another copy. If you see it somewhere just let me know. I searched the whole web. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see [the jFormer's documentation](http://www.jformer.com/documentation/getting-started/installation/) you'll need similar as I've created [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) integration:

```
// File libraries/Smarty_tpl.php
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

//smarty class
require "/usr/share/php/smarty3/libs/Smarty.class.php";


class Smarty_tpl extends Smarty {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    $smarty_dir = "/usr/share/php/smarty3/libs/";

    $this->setTemplateDir(APPPATH."views/templates");
    $this->setCompileDir(APPPATH."views/templates_c");
    $this->setCacheDir(APPPATH."views/cache");
    $this->setConfigDir(APPPATH."views/config");
    $this->setPluginsDir(array("$smarty_dir/plugins","$smarty_dir/sysplugins/"));
    $this->compile_check=   true;
    $this->force_compile=   true;
    $this->caching=         false;
    $this->cache_lifetime=  86400;
 }
}
```

And it's usage:

```
$this->load->library("smarty_tpl");
$this->smarty_tpl->display("myform.tpl");
```

And of course don't forget to include `css` and `js` files!

Comment: I have jFormer working however it's not integrated with Codeigniter form helper and I am not sure if it was done correctly. I just added the linked libraries from view while the jFormer library is located in the root folder.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do this simply, because as I see jFormer doesn't have any function that returns the string of generated source (html-tags, etc.) - and IMHO this needed to use `echo jformer_table(...)` and similar. I think you should create own `"view"` library (e.g. `jf_view`) and you'll call `jf_view`'s functions instead of main `view`. Maybe exists any better solution but I don't know better...